# TikZ fading doesn't move with scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

There's almost certainly something I'm missing here but I'd like a faded drawing to be defined and placed at various points in the picture.  I can get it to look how I want, but when I place it in `\begin{scope}[xshift=\x,yshift=\y]` environment, the fading doesn't move with the rest of what's in the scope.

Here's a stripped-down example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{flameshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!0);color(3mm)=(pgftransparent!40);color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!70);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadeflame}{\pgfuseshading{flameshade}}

\def\flame{
    \pgfsetfading{fadeflame}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0}{-4.5}}\pgftransformxscale{0.05}\pgftransformyscale{0.08}}%
    \path(0,0) pic{flame};
}
    \tikzset{%
  flame/.pic={
    code={
        \tikzset{scale=1/10}
        \node[circle,minimum height=4, minimum width=4, fill=\fillcolour,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at(0,-1){};

  }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (-4,-3) rectangle (6,4);

\node[circle,inner sep=0, outer sep=0, draw=white,very thin] at (0,0){};

\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=-0cm]
    \def\fillcolour{yellow}
    \flame
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=.1cm, yshift=-0.1cm]
    \def\fillcolour{cyan}
    \flame
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of above code, heavily cropped]

The white circle just indicates the origin.  The yellow shaded circle looks right; when I shift it the fading stays behind (as seen from the cyan shaded circle).

Comment: It seems you have to give **all** transformations to `\pgfsetfading`.

Comment: @Symbol1 which implies a rewrite to draw a faded item at a particular location, rather than draw and move it.  I'll have a try later on

Comment: I just proposed an answer. This is by no means the only approach. You can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may redefine `\frame` as follows

```
\def\flame{
    \pgfgettransform{\mycurrenttransform}
    \pgfsetfading{fadeflame}{
        \pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0}{-4.5}}\pgftransformxscale{0.05}\pgftransformyscale{0.08}}%
    \path(0,0) pic{flame};
}
```

Here, `\pgfgettransform` will store the current transformation in `\mycurrenttransform` and `\pgfsettransform` will restore it in `\pgfsetfading`. That is, it now remembers where you are.

[image]

Comment: When I replied to your comment, your answer loaded.  This could be very useful elsewhere in this drawing too.  Again, I'll have a go later on.